# Express logging color format

Tags: node.js, express

Newbie here.

In express 3.2.6 I noticed that when you set the logging to `app.use(express.logger('dev'))` the format of the log in stdout is greyed out and easy on the eyes (dark mode?), like so:

[image]

However, when using express 4.0 and using morgan for logging with the following in app.js

```
var morgan = require('morgan');
app.use(morgan('dev'));
```

The logging in terminal turns out like this

[image]

Anyway to get the "dark mode" theme for logging using express 4.0 and morgan? Or is this just available in express 3.0?

Looks like this can be modified to accomplish this? https://github.com/expressjs/morgan/blob/master/index.js#L183

Answer (score 1):

Well You can customize your logger colors by making a custom logger try this

```
//logger.js
require('colors');
var _ = require('lodash');
var config = require('../config/config');

// create a noop (no operation) function for when loggin is disabled
var noop = function () {
};
// check if loggin is enabled in the config
// if it is, then use console.log
// if not then noop
var consoleLog = config.logging ? console.log.bind(console) : noop;

var logger = {
  log: function () {
    var tag = '[ ✨ LOG ✨ ]'.green;
    // arguments is an array like object with all the passed
    // in arguments to this function
    var args = _.toArray(arguments)
        .map(function (arg) {
          if (typeof arg === 'object') {
            // turn the object to a string so we
            // can log all the properties and color it
            var string = JSON.stringify(arg, null, 2);
            return tag + '  ' + string.cyan;
          } else {
            return tag + '  ' + arg.cyan;
          }
        });

    // call either console.log or noop here
    // with the console object as the context
    // and the new colored args :)
    consoleLog.apply(console, args);
  },

  error: function () {
    var args = _.toArray(arguments)
        .map(function (arg) {
          arg = arg.stack || arg;
          var name = arg.name || '[ ❌ ERROR ❌ ]';
          var log = name.yellow + '  ' + arg.red;
          return log;
        });

    consoleLog.apply(console, args);
  }
};

module.exports = logger;
```

usage

```
//controller
var logger = require('./relative/path/to/logger');
logger.log('some thing');
logger.error('some thing');
// you may use custom colors and create custom functions like warning() etc
```

hope it helps ;)